# Jquery find if div reached the bottom on scroll

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, content-management-system

I cant get this tot work, what is the problem?

```
$("#scrollingbox").scroll(function() { //detect page scroll

    if($("#scrollingbox").scrollTop() + $("#scrollingbox").height() == $("#scrollingbox").height())  //user scrolled to bottom of the page?
    {
            //do something
        }
 }
```

what happens is i need to scroll up again for it to detect that it reached the bottom.

Comment: scrollTop is always >= 0. So essentially you're asking if something that's always >= 0 + X is equal to X, that condition will be true when scroll is == 0. I.E. when no scroll has been done. You can see this differs from detecting reaching the bottom.

Answer (score 5):

http://jsfiddle.net/collabcoders/v2RbN/1/

```
$("span").hide();

$(".box").scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
        $("span").show();    
    } else {
        $("span").hide();
    }
})
```

Comment: If you want to use DOM methods, don't create a jQuery object and then throw it away, just use the DOM: `this.scrollHeight` (instead of `$(this)[0].scrollHeight`), also: please cache variables if you're using them repeatedly.