# How to detect the scrolling of each div and not the entire window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created an html page where the window doesn't scroll but the divs inside the window scroll and have scroll bars. I have searched and found this jquery to **detect the scrolling of the window and find the position of scrolling for each div**. Accordingly I modified it to detect scrolling for the left div, but it doesn't seem to be working.

The jquery script that I've got so far:

```
$("#le").scroll(function() {
        console.log("Entered");
        alert("Working!");
        var height = $("#le").scrollTop()
        console.log(height);
    });
```

Here's a simple JSFiddle that contains a basic html: https://jsfiddle.net/8q5e4u8q/

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

**UPDATE:** Got the solution. Apparently shifting the script tag below the body tag did the trick! Thanks for all the tips and help. Cheers!

Comment: Your fiddle does not have jquery in it. It's working just fine after adding the link to jquery.

Comment: JSFiddle is convenient but it would be better to have a complete verifiable example withing the question

Comment: I've been making an entire jsfiddle and been looking around to just see this @you.know.nothing haha easy solution, should've looked better.

Comment: @AngelofDemons: Let's see whether OP was really looking for this :P

Comment: It's funny I linked the Jquery and it works just fine. But strangely it doesn't work on my local html file. I have linked the jquery as follows:

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#le").scroll(function() {
            console.log("Entered");
            alert("Working!");
            var height = $("#le").scrollTop();
            console.log(height);
        });
    </script>

Comment: Check in your browser's network tab (of Developer Tools) for jquery. See if it failed to load.

Comment: @you.know.nothing I checked the network tab and the jquery file has loaded properly. I even uploaded the code on my domain but it still fails to execute the query as it did on jsfiddle. Also, the window.scroll query which I don't need to detect runs fine locally but I can't seem to get it working for individual divs.

Comment: **window.scroll query which I don't need to detect runs fine** - that means you are binding scroll event to your elements before they are even inserted into DOM.

Comment: I got the solution. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

> **EDIT: as said in the comments:
>
>   Your fiddle does not have jquery in it. It's working just fine after adding the link to jquery.**

I don't *exactly* know what if im understanding correctly what you are asking for. But I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211787/detect-div-scroll-jquery) and found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/collabcoders/v2RbN/1/) solution and edited to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/v2RbN/694/)

Now if you *scroll* in the *first* box it alerts_ *scrolling* but if you scroll in the second it will ***not***  alert the *scrolling* You probably have to change the names and such but should work correctly.

```js
$(".box").scroll(function() {
 alert('scrolling');
});
```

```css
    div.box, .second-box {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      overflow: scroll;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="box">
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content... <br>
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content...
    </div>
    <div class="second-box">
    lalaa
    alalaa<br />
    our text content...<br>
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content... <br>
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content...<br>
         All your text content...
    </div>
```