# $(window).on('scroll', function() { not highlighting and working when scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

For some strange reason my `$(window).on('scroll', function() {` is not highlighting the navigation on the left when scrolling. The code I have written is correct. Not sure why its not functioning correctly Any idea why it won't highlight when scrolling? 
Here is a link to my codepen: https://codepen.io/j1osu2006/pen/XWbbgoB

```
<script>

    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        $('h2').each(function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(this).offset().top) {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                $('#toc li a').removeClass('active');
                $('a[href$="'+id+'"]').addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You're listening for the window scroll event when the scroll bar is on a div. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211787/detect-div-scroll-jquery

Comment: I got it to scroll correctly. I ended up changing `$(window).on('scroll', function() {` to: `$(".content").scroll(function() {` Thank you so much for that link. Much appreciation!